# Update quantity after adding same product to shopping basket

Tags: php, shopping-cart, product-quantity

I can't figure out how to update the quantity of a product which is already in the shopping basket by adding it again. If the quantity is 1, after adding same product with  quantity 3, it should show 4 in the basket. All I can do at the moment is either replace the added quantity with the new one or insert an empty element in the basket table with no product details whatsoever.

```
<?php
// Products are added to the basket
if (!isset($_SESSION['basket'])) {
  $_SESSION['basket'] = array();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['basket'][$_POST['id']] = array(
    'product_id'=>($_POST['id']),
    'product_photo'=>($_POST['hidden_photo']),
    'product_photo_alt'=>($_POST['hidden_photo_alt']),
    'product_name'=>($_POST['hidden_name']),
    'product_price'=>($_POST['hidden_price']),
    'product_quantity'=>($_POST['quantity'])
    );
  }
}

// This is the code with which I can only insert an empty element in the basket table with no product details.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['basket'][$_POST['id']] as $item) {
        if ($_item['product_id'] === $_SESSION['basket']['product_id']) {
          $_SESSION['basket']['product_quantity'] += $item['product_quantity']; 
        } 
    }    
  }   
}

// If I apply below code it just replaces the quantity:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item) {
        if ($_item['product_id'] === [$_POST['id']]) {
          $item['product_quantity'] += $_POST['quantity']; 
        } 
    }    
  }   
}
?>
```

[image: Quantity replaced]
[image: Empty element inserted]

Please let me know if you require more details.

**UPDATE**

I wrote another code but this time it just doubles the quantity sent to shopping basket. I also added one hidden input field on the page where products are listed.

Code on the page where products are listed and where you add them to basket:

```
<form> // Submitted via Ajax
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="do_it" value="quantity_again"/> // New input field added
    <select name="quantity">
                <?php
                // Drop-down select quantity menu 
                for ($i=1; $i<=$row['stock']; $i++) {
                ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>

                <?php
                }   
                ?>
    </select>
  </div>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_photo" value="<?php echo $row['img_front_url']; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_photo_alt" value="<?php echo $row['img_front_alt'];?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row['product']; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"/>
        <button class="add-to-basket">Add to basket</button>
</form>
```

The new code which only doubles the quantity in the basket.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (isset($_POST['do_it']) && $_POST['do_it'] == 'quantity_again') {
    foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as &$item) {
        if ($item['product_id'] === $_POST['id']) {
          $item['product_quantity'] += $_POST['quantity'];
        } 
    }    
  }   
}
```

It seems that `$item['product_quantity']` and `$_POST['quantity']` are the same, so that's why the quantity gets doubled. 
I thought that I would need to check first if `$_POST['quantity']` exists in the array `$_SESSION['basket']` and if it does, store it in a variable and then do `$item['product_quantity'] += $stored_qty` but that just again overrides the quantity. Here's the code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (isset($_POST['do_it']) && $_POST['do_it'] == 'quantity_again') {
    foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item) {
      if (in_array($_POST['quantity'], $_SESSION['basket'])) {
        $stored_qty = $_POST['quantity']; 
          if ($item['product_id'] === $_POST['id']) {
            $item['product_quantity'] += $stored_qty;
          } 
      }  
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: In the last block of code can you `var_dump()`  the `$item` inside for each loop and post what you get?

Comment: I did `var_dump($item)` in the foreach loop but there is no result, nothing at all.

Comment: That's strange... It should display the previously added items in the basket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (isset($_POST['do_it']) && $_POST['do_it'] == 'change') {
    if (isset($_SESSION['basket'])) {
      $is_available = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $keys => $values) {
          if ($_SESSION['basket'][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST['id']) {
            $is_available++;
            $_SESSION['basket'][$keys]['product_quantity'] +=  $_POST['quantity'];
          } 
        } 
    }

    if ($is_available == 0) {
      if (!isset($_SESSION['basket'])) {
        $_SESSION['basket'] = array();
      }

      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
          $_SESSION['basket'][$_POST['id']] = array(
          'product_id'=>($_POST['id']),
          'product_photo'=>($_POST['hidden_photo']),
          'product_photo_alt'=>($_POST['hidden_photo_alt']),
          'product_name'=>($_POST['hidden_name']),
          'product_price'=>($_POST['hidden_price']),
          'product_quantity'=>($_POST['quantity'])
          );
        }
      }   
    }  
  }   
}
```

Credit goes to https://www.webslesson.info/2018/04/shopping-cart-by-using-bootstrap-popover-with-ajax-php.html

Although, I'm not sure if I understand what `$is_available` actually does in the code and how  it refers to increasing quantity when same product is added.